# Usage of 'Less than' condition in Sum

Tags: summation, conditional, boolean-computation

I have following sum: $$ \sum_{\substack{n,j\\j<n}}^{3} x_nx_j$$. How can I give this $j<n$ condition in `Sum`?

Comment: `Table[x[n] x[j], {n, 1, 3}, {j, n, 3}] // Flatten // Total`

Comment: Sorry @cvgmt, j shall be lower n. This is the right: `Table[x[n] x[j], {n, 1, 3}, {j, 1, n - 1}] // Flatten // Total `

Comment: @Akku14 Thanks you, you are right.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For more complex condition:

```
Sum[Boole[j<n] x[n] x[j] ,{n,1,3},{j,1,3}]
```

For this simple condition:

@cvgmt give it as comment.

---

Just for fun:

```
Subsets[Array[x, 3], {2}] // Map[Apply@Times] // Total
```

Comment: thank you. I have used Boole to provide equal or not equal condition in sum previously; I was confused about whether it can be useful in this case also,

Answer (score 4):

The most direct solution is simply:

```
Sum[x[n] x[j], {n, 1, 3}, {j, 1, n}]
```

(* x[1]^2 + x[1]*x[2] + x[2]^2 + x[1]*x[3] + x[2]*x[3] + x[3]^2 *)

The same sort of thing works with NSum, Product and Product.

Comment: I think you are almost right. Just the upper limit of j should be n-1.

Answer (score 3):

```
SparseArray[{n_, j_} /; j < n -> Subscript[x, n] Subscript[x, j], {3, 
    3}] // Flatten // Total
```

Answer (score 2):

As usual, there are several ways to do it with Mathematica depending on the specific features that you want. Suppose you
want to do some processing on all cases where $i<j$ where
$i,j$ are in some range or list. The following code, in order
of complexity, will each produce such a list of tuples:

```
r = Range[3];
Subsets[r, {2}]
Cases[Tuples[r, 2],  {i_,j_}/;i<j]
Select[Tuples[r, 2], #[[1]]<#[[2]]&]
Flatten[Table[If[i<j, {i,j}, Nothing], {i,r},{j,r}]
```

Once you have such a list `L` of `{i,j}` tuples, then you can
find the sum of `f[i,j]` over all tuples with code such as:

```
Plus@@(L /. {i_,j_}->f[i,j])
Plus@@(# /. ij_->f@@ij& /@ L)
```

Same thing with the product using `Times` instead of `Sum`.